# Set Dockpanel size in grid programmatically

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, dockpanel

*My goal is to programmatically set a DockPanel size.
I want it to span from Grid.Column=1, Grid.Row=1, Grid.RowSpan=5*

And I know hot to set it statically in xaml, but not in c#.

**Explanation to code:** In xaml I made a 1row 1 column grid with some textfields and a button in the DockPanel. In when I press the button it should create a grid with as many column/rows as I wrote in the textfields. Then name each column and each row. And know I want to create a Dockpanel on some of these fields but for that I must define where it starts and how far it spans. This is where the problem is.

here is my xaml code how I made it:

```
<Grid Name="MainWindowGrid">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Name="DockPanel"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <DockPanel Background="LightSalmon" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.RowSpan="8">
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBox Name="txtColums" Text="16"/>
            <TextBox Name="txtRows" Text="8"/>
            <TextBox Name="txtWindowHeight" Text="800"/>
            <TextBox Name="txtWindowWidth" Text="1600"/>

            <Button x:Name="ButtonCreate" Content="Create" Click="ButtonCreate_Click"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </DockPanel>
    <ContentControl Content="{Binding}"/>
</Grid>
```

And my C# code what I have so far:

```
Methods Methods = new Methods();
Methods.CreateField(MainWindowGrid, txtColums, txtRows, txtWindowHeight, txtWindowWidth, MainWindow1);

int GridColumnCount = MainWindowGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Count;
int GridRowCount = MainWindowGrid.RowDefinitions.Count;

for (int a = 1; a < GridColumnCount; a++)
{
    MainWindowGrid.ColumnDefinitions.ElementAt(a).Name = "C" + a;
}
for (int a = 1; a < GridRowCount; a++)
{
    MainWindowGrid.RowDefinitions.ElementAt(a).Name = "R" + a;
}

var converter = new System.Windows.Media.BrushConverter();
var brush1 = (Brush)converter.ConvertFromString("#FFFFFFF0");
DockPanel myDockPanel = new DockPanel();
myDockPanel.Background = brush1;
myDockPanel.
```

At the very end I want to be able to set at which row/column the dockpanel should be and then span it, but I sadly do not know how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the following methods to set the `Grid.Column`, `Grid.Row` and `Grid.RowSpan` attached properties of `myDockPanel`:

```
Grid.SetColumn(myDockPanel, 1); //= <DockPanel ... Grid.Column = "1"
Grid.SetRow(myDockPanel, 1); //= <DockPanel ... Grid.Row = "1"
Grid.SetRowSpan(myDockPanel, 8); //= <DockPanel ... Grid.RowSpan = "8"
```